# O(n log n) sorting approach for finding the number of pairs that add up to a specific sum

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

So I pretty much have the code correct I believe. The only thing is can't seem to get the same answers with the sorting approach that I can with the O(n^2) brute force approach. For context I am getting the correct answer with the brute force approach but the sorting approach just isn't working. Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Here is my code:

```
int getNumPairs(int nums[], int& size, int& sum) {
    if (size < 2) {
        return 0;
    }
    sort(nums, nums + size);

    int left = 0;
    int right = size - 1;
    int count = 0;

    while (left < right) {
        if (nums[left] + nums[right] == sum) {
            count++;
        }
        (nums[left] + nums[right] < sum)? left++: right--;
    }
    return count;
}

void bruteForce(int nums[], int& size, int& sum) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == sum) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Brute Force count for sum of " << sum << " is: " << count << endl;
}
```

Here is my output for both functions:

```
Brute Force count for sum of 4 is: 4
Number of pairs that add to 4: 3
```

Here is the array I'm working with and the sum I need to find:

```
int arr[] = {2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0};
int sum = 4;
int size = 6;
```

I would really appreciate any help that can be given thanks.

Comment: @user17732522 sorry, I meant to tag it C++, but it still works the same way with the same algorithms in java.

Comment: Have you tried to use debugger with step?

Comment: @LouisGo Yeah, but I couldn't really see what would be the problem. From the other resources I've looked at this seems to be the correct way, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Some pen and paper debugging might be useful. Run through the steps of your sorting two-pointer algorithm on `[1, 1, 3, 3], sum = 4` and see what it does.

Comment: Why do you check for (size -1 ) < 2? You'll return 0 for arrays of size 2 that way. What if those two values form a pair with the correct sum? Also, you are not updating left and right correctly when you have found a pair. For exampe, if the sum you look for is 4 and you have the input 1 1 3. You'll check the first 1 vs the last 3. But then you move right. You should move left instead, to check the 2nd 1 against the last 3.

Comment: @StefanKempf Yeah I realized that a little bit ago and changed it, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Another input to pen&paper debugging was [2, 2, 2].

Answer (score 1):

You have issue when array have duplicate

with

```
[x x .. y y]
 ^        ^
```

with `x+y == sum`

you do

```
count++
[x x .. y y]
 ^      ^
```

and then

```
count++
[x x .. y y]
 ^    ^
```

second `x` won't match any values.
(even worst when `x == y`)

```
if (nums[left] + nums[right] == sum) {
    count++;
}
(nums[left] + nums[right] < sum)? left++: right--;
```

has to be changed:

```
if (nums[left] + nums[right] == sum) {
    // skip and count duplicates
    const auto oldLeft = left;
    do {
        ++left;
    } while (left <= right && nums[oldLeft] == nums[left]);
    const auto oldRight = right;
    do {
        --right;
    } while (left <= right && nums[oldRight] == nums[right]);

    // resulting count
    count += (arr[oldLeft] == arr[oldRight]
             ? (left - oldLeft) * (left - oldLeft - 1) / 2
             : ((left - oldLeft) * (oldRight - right)));
}
else
    (nums[left] + nums[right] < sum) ? left++: right--;
```